# why we don't use [ ] (dimension) while calculating length of an array

Tags: java

```
    Example-1
        //called
        void display(int x[])
        {    
            
            for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
                System.out.println(x[i]);   
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {   
            int a[]= {1,2,3};
            Demo ob=new Demo();
            //calling
            ob.display(a);
        

Example-2    
    
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int l = a.length;
```

**In example -1**, while calling we have written array a without dimension but during called we have passed it to a parameter x[] with dimension that is an array type.even **In example 2** during calculating length of an array we calculate the length without dimension just with . operator along with length property so
shouldn't we use here a along with dimension like **a[]** during calling  we have to pass it to  an array type variable. as well as during calculating length **a[].length**

Comment: Qbrute. i understood, what you wants to say that. Please tell me one thing.look at my code and tell me how a[] array elements are changing with changing in x[ ] array?

Comment: if you would use syntax of `int[] a` there would not be confusion i guess

Answer (score 0):

Its simmple. `a` is a `car`, `display` is a carwash, and `x` is car during the cleaning.

You drive your `car` trough `carwash` and it gets clean afterwards. But it is still the same car - only modified somehow.

The same occures here - you pass array, you modify that array (its elements) and it stays modified.

Comment: Please check edit question